# How to solve DBUpdateException on Delete action

Tags: c#, wpf, database, database-design, crud

using VS 2012, C#, WPF

Try to create simple program that use database. Target to implement CRUD operation in programm. Currently I'm a little bit stack on DELETE action - during deleting got exception `DBUpdateException`

[image]

Inner exception

[image]

InnerException text - `{"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_SpecialityStudent\". The conflict occurred in database \"EducationDataBase\", table \"dbo.StudentSet\", column 'SpecialitySpecialityId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

As I understand, I can't delete this entry in table, due to usage of entry in another table (StudentSet). But when i create my dataBase, i make 1 to many relationShip between table, mean

[image]

If I try to delete entry of SpecialitySet, that not used in another tables - all ok.
So regarding DELETING, I suggest, that relationShip in such manner (like on pic) mean that I can delete Speciality entry in any time, even if I use it in another table. Am i right?  If no - can you explain me a little bit more detailed how can i delete such entry. Or maybe I make mistake in my dataBase during creating. (**Question**)

Code that I use for deleting

```
private async void _deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to remove speciality " + _specialityNameTextBox.Text + " ?",
            "Remove Speciality", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new EducationDataBaseEntities())
            {
                foreach (var item in dbContext.SpecialitySet)
                {
                    if (item.Name == _specialityNameTextBox.Text
                        && item.Description == _descriptionTextBox.Text)
                    {
                        dbContext.SpecialitySet.Remove(item);
                        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        MessageBox.Show("Speciality " + item.Description + "removed correctly",
                            "Remove speciality", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                       await LoadDataFromDB(this._specialityDataGrid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Operation canceled", "Canceled");
        }
    }
```

Also, if I left dataBase as is now, how can i delete entry that already used? or I cant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You can not delete a row from SpecialitySet that is references from StudentSet, because there is a Foreign Key setup named `FK_SpecialityStudent`, that is enforcing referential integrity. This is one of the reasons a Foreign Keys exists -- to guarantee that orphaned records are not created.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx

Typically what you would do is first delete the associated rows from StudentSet, then the row from SpecialitySet.

Alternatively, You can change `FK_SpecialityStudent` to cascade deletes. Which means when you delete a row from SpecialitySet, then all associated rows from StudentSet will also be deleted. To do this check out the `ON DELETE CASCADE` examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx